# Android ListView does not gets selected when an OnClickListener is set

Tags: android, android-listview

I am using Listview with custom Adapter and a selector which I have set as background of the listview row item parent layout. When I am not setting OnClick listener to the parent layout of the listview item, the selector is working fine and the row gets selected.
But as soon as I am setting OnClick listener to the parent layout of the listview item , the selector is not working. **I don't want to use onItemClickListener** as I have to take care of certain things from the ListView Adapter.

I have been searching for this for hours but didn't got any clue. 
Please help.
Thanks

**My Custom Adapter class**

```
    public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private final String[] mNotificationList;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;
    private Activity mActivity;

    public CustomAdapter(Activity activity,String[] data) {
        mActivity = activity;
        mNotificationList = data;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)       activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        if(mNotificationList == null){
            return 0;
        }           
        else{
            return mNotificationList.length;
        }           
    }
    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int id) {
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View converterView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (converterView == null){
            converterView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.notification_list_row, null);
        }

        NotificationListHolder listRowHolder =     (NotificationListHolder)converterView.getTag();

        if(listRowHolder==null) {
           listRowHolder = new NotificationListHolder();
           initializeView(listRowHolder,converterView);
        }

        bindView(listRowHolder,mNotificationList[position]);
        return converterView;
    }

    private void bindView(NotificationListHolder listRowHolder, String notificationDetails) {
        listRowHolder.articleName.setText(notificationDetails);
        listRowHolder.parentLayout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(mActivity, "TOAST",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
    }

    private void initializeView(NotificationListHolder listRowHolder,View converterView) {
        listRowHolder.parentLayout = (LinearLayout) converterView.findViewById(R.id.notificationlist_row_layout);
        listRowHolder.articleName = (TextView) converterView.findViewById(R.id.article_text);
        converterView.setTag(listRowHolder);
    }

    public static class NotificationListHolder{
        public LinearLayout parentLayout;
        public TextView articleName;
    }
}
```

**list row item xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/notificationlist_row_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/list_selector" >




    <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/article_text"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="40dp"

                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

     <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
                    android:text="second view" 
                    android:layout_below="@+id/article_text"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**list selector xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

     <item 
        android:state_selected="true" 
        android:drawable="@color/msg_read_bg" />

     <item 
        android:state_pressed="true" 
        android:drawable="@color/msg_read_bg" />
    <item 
        android:state_activated="true" 
        android:drawable="@color/msg_read_bg" />
     <item 
        android:state_active="true" 
        android:drawable="@color/msg_read_bg" />

    <item 
        android:state_focused="true" 
        android:drawable="@color/msg_read_bg" />

     <item android:drawable="@android:color/white" /> 
</selector>
```

Comment: But onTouchListener listener will be invoked even if the user doesn;t intends to select the list item or even when the list view is scrolled. :(

Comment: I found the soultion myself after trying for multiple hours. Need to set the targetsdkversion to 15 in the manifest file